# Angular formgroup is not working

Tags: angular, checkbox, formgroups

I want to get the array of checked values using FormGroup instead of FormBuilder.

I followed the code from the below stackblitz link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stszta

The form created using FormBuilder I replaced it with FormGroup. When I submit the form the checkbox is retuning all false values though I checked.

> this.formBuilder.group // replaced this line with new FormGroup({

```
this.form = new FormGroup({
      orders: new FormArray(controls, minSelectedCheckboxes(1))
    });
```

Comment: what do you want. already there everything. if you want all checkbox to be selected default use this.orders.map(c => new FormControl(true));

Comment: Welcome Krishna. It isn't clear what you're asking, looks like you didn't finish writing your question. Take a look at this guide for writing Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable examples, the SO community is much more likely to help if contributors can figure out what you need quickly: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I just reframed my question. Please help me out.